# Remove default style from boostrap anchor link

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to remove the default styling from the `a` tag.

What I am trying to achieve is, to place the `a` tag and other things in one line only. But, the default `a` tag styling is not allowing me.

Here's the code:

```
<table style="background: #DEE3E0" class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr style="padding: 0">
            <th class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 0">Name & Qty</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px; width: 50px;padding: 0">Rate</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="font-size: 12px; width: 50px;padding: 0">Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 12px">
                <img src="//placehold.it/45" alt="Product Image" />
                1x  <a href="" style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
                        Product Name
                    </a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Remove">
                        <span class="pull-right text-danger">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right" style="padding-top: 7.5px; font-size: 12px">150.00</td>
            <td class="text-right" style="padding-top: 7.5px; font-size: 12px">150.00</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- and other rows... -->
    </tbody>
    
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold" class="text-right">Sub Total</td>
            <td class="text-right" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">425.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 12px" class="text-right">Taxes</td>
            <td style="font-size: 12px" class="text-right">50.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 12px" colspan="2" class="text-right">Shipping</td>
            <td style="font-size: 12px" class="text-right">100.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold" colspan="2" class="text-right">Grand Total</td>
            <td style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold" class="text-right">575.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="font-weight: bold; color: #65C400; margin-top: -10px">View Cart</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="font-weight: bold; color: #65C400;" class="pull-right">Checkout</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Here's the complete fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j4o8tff5/

`1x` is the quantity. I want that `Product Name` should be placed next to the quantity itself. And hence I am trying to remove the default styling.

I have searched a lot, but could not find the solution.

Kindly help me out. Thanks.

Comment: can you show expected output as a image?

Comment: @Amit The output should be `1x` `Product Name`(having the link)..

Comment: @user3514160 Isn't that already like that?

Comment: @SharathDaniel Kindly check the demo given by stanze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your quantity text in span tag, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/j4o8tff5/1/)

```
<span>1x</span>
```

Comment: @user3514160 Select it as an answer.

Comment: I need to wait for 6 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to find out the default styling, better you use some styling to achieve your target. simply use -

a{ position: relative; top: -12px; }

this will solve your problem.

Comment: I appreciate your help and answer sir, but I already got my solution. Thanks for your input too..